# SQLite UPDATE submits null data if using data from $_POST

Tags: php, sqlite, post, null

I'm trying to update a table in PHP with SQLite. My code is the following:

```
//Get params like this
$title = $_POST['title'];
...
$params = array($visible, $link, $title, $post, $month, $day, $year, $sub3);
$query = "UPDATE posts SET visible = ?, link = ?, title = ?, entries = ?, month = ?, day = ?, year = ? WHERE id = ?; COMMIT;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($params);
```

If I get the values from $_POST, by the time it does the execute on the statement, 99% of the time, null values are updated in the fields instead of the $_POST data ($sub3 is not from $_POST).

If I hard code the values, it works fine. I also have an insert statement in the same code path (checks to see if it's new data first, if not do the INSERT). Insert works fine every time (data from $_POST).

Also, I have code like this for three other tables, all of which work. This is the only table that doesn't. Nothing different about set up of table compared to others.

This one works on a different table:

```
$params = array($name, $username, $email, $level, $sub3);
$query = "UPDATE users SET name = ?, username = ?, email = ?, level = ? WHERE id = ?; COMMIT;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($params);
```

I've tried bindParam, bindValue, and creating the statement string manually without prepare, but as long as it's from $_POST, it won't work.

What am I missing? Anything else I can try?

Comment: are you sure `$_post` is not empty?

Comment: Please note that `COMMIT` is not allowed without a corresponding `BEGIN`. Furthermore, PHP will execute only the first `;`-delimited command in a query string.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the commit is left over from my old old old test.

Also, $_POST is not empty. I've printed it out many times. Also, the INSERT path which uses that same initialization part works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Print the POST variables and check if it has the right data.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

EDIT: 
Change the query.

```
//$params = array($visible, $link, $title, $post, $month, $day, $year, $sub3);
$query = "UPDATE posts SET visible = '$visible', link = '$link', title = '$title', entries = '$entries', month = '$month', day = '$day', year = '$year' WHERE id = $id;  COMMIT;";
```

Make sure you have the correct $id

Comment: This is not a answer, but a comment

Comment: I am sorry about that. Didn't realize. Shall i delete ?

Comment: This is print_r($_POST) right after the $stmt->execute($params);

Array ( [visible] => visible [title] => Test [date] => 10/14/2012 [cat] => 0 [post] => Test [submit] => Save )

Comment: Good. So you are getting proper values from POST. Can you write the full UPDATE query here. I just want to see if you are making any mistakes with quotes.

Comment: Should be this, $query = "UPDATE posts SET visible = ?, link = ?, title = ?, entries = ?, month = ?, day = ?, year = ? WHERE id = ?;";

Comment: Correct. But instead of "?" are you using variables like $title or you are directly using POST variables like $_POST['title']

Comment: Ah, I'm using variables like $title.
$params = array($visible, $link, $title, $post, $month, $day, $year, $sub3);
$sub3 isn't from $_POST, which is why the UPDATE actually updates a row. Everything else is more or less directly from $_POST.

Comment: Alright, umm, maybe you can try to echo $stmt. It will print the query. Check if it has all correct syntax. Can you print it here if its ok for you ?

Comment: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => UPDATE posts SET visible = ?, link = ?, title = ?, entries = ?, month = ?, day = ?, year = ? WHERE id = ?; )

Comment: Are you replacing real values with ? or you are actually getting the "?"

Comment: That's exactly as it's printing to me. It's the same way for an UPDATE on a different table that works.

Comment: This is weird. Alright, do not use the $params array. Its not required. Change your query. I will edit my answer and write the query for better formatting.

Comment: Tried what you said but doesn't work still. Null values for all but id This is the $stmt, PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => UPDATE posts SET visible = '1', link = 'test', title = 'Test', entries = 'Test', month = '10', day = '24', year = '2012' WHERE id = 10 ).

Comment: Hmmm. I am sorry, not getting any clues at the moment. I will think about this. Will let you know if any alarm bell rings in my mind.